# Android bm.copy NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap

I have NullPointerException problem on following code:

```
if(bm != null) {
   mTempBitmap = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
}
```

and there are users who report following crash on my Google Play dev console:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:647)
 *****
```

Maybe I'm missing something out about how Java/Android works. Can someone can explain why/how created objects can be destroyed in middle of active activity? Even if check statement returns that the object isn't null?

The crash report count isn't big comparing to daily active user count, but still it's indicate the problem and obviously crash app on some users. Also it's not device specific problem and I get reports from devices such: Galaxy S4, Nexus 4, Galaxy S5, Xperia Z1 etc.

No matter how hard I try I can't create such situation on my devices or emulators.

Comment: "Even if check statement returns that the object isn't null?" -- the `Bitmap` is not `null`. Otherwise, you would not have even gotten into line 647 of `Bitmap.java`.

Comment: You are right. Looks like I got some mental hiccup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bm.getConfig()` is returning null (which it is [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getConfig()) as being allowed to do).

(The problem can't be that `bm` itself is null, because you check that, and because you wouldn't even get into the `copy()` function if it was. So you must be passing a null to the function. And it sure isn't `true`.)

Comment: Thanks! My bad. Sometimes can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Am I too stupid that still i didnt understand how to solve or may be I have got mental hiccups too